# Working between PHP library and JS library in Mixpanel

Tags: javascript, php, mixpanel

I am new to Mixpanel and currently wondering how can i work between Mixpanel's JS library and PHP library.

Let say that i have the following (simple) JS script:

```
// Placed on homepage
<script type="text/javascript">
  mixpanel.track("viewed homepage");
</script>

// Placed on category page
<script type="text/javascript">
  mixpanel.track("viewed category page");
</script>

// Placed on product page
<script type="text/javascript">
  mixpanel.track("viewed product page");
</script>
```

So when John Doe (jdoe@example.com) visit my website at http://example.com, he first lands on the homepage and then navigate away to category page and browse for some products (john might go back and forth between category page and product page).

As far as i know, John will be assigned with some random ID (distinct id) from Mixpanel (e.g. 123123).

I also have this PHP code:

```
$mp->identify("jdoe@example.com");

$mp->people->set(XYZ, array(
    '$first_name'       => "John",
    '$last_name'        => "Doe",
    '$email'            => "john.doe@example.com",
    '$phone'            => "5555555555"
));

$mp->people->increment(XYZ, "login count", 1);
```

According to the Mixpanel docs here found here https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/php

"XYZ" should be Mixpanel distinct id, which in this case is set to 123123 for our John Doe.

So the question would be, how can i know the assigned distinct id set by Mixpanel to John Doe using PHP library knowing that he has previously been assigned a distinct id (via JS library) ?

I also notice that when using Mixpanel's PHP library, it doesn't automatically assigned randomly generated distinct id as compared to using JS library (see image for details):

[image: Mixpanel]

***EDIT 1***

So i found this code on the docs:

```
// set distinct_id after the mixpanel library has loaded
mixpanel.init("YOUR PROJECT TOKEN", {
    loaded: function() {
        distinct_id = mixpanel.get_distinct_id();
    }
});
```

Which basically can retrieve the distinct_id set by Mixpanel, and wondering whether it is possible to retrieve the distinct_id via PHP (presumably the distinct_id is stored in the cookies).

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting only name, surname, email and other "simple" informations on user profile you can do it in JavaScript, importing datas from the PHP, without mixing PHP and JS Mixpanel Apis.
You should also set an ID to the user that is the same ID you have in your database, to be sure that you can recognize user in any session/device.

Something like that:

```
        mixpanel.identify("41");
        mixpanel.people.set({
            "$first_name": "Name",
            "$last_name": "Surname",
            "$email": "Mail@gmail.com",
            "$last_login": "2016-02-11 09:00:08",
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a step in my funnel that requires the use of PHP library. Hence, i need to know whether this is possible.

Comment: I faced quite the same issue and that was the only workaround that worked - running only javascript api and passing data from php to be tracked.

Comment: @AlexanderM.I think i might find a workaround, but not sure that it is the correct answert to do it. I can share it with you if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the same **session id** for both libraries:

As [docs](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/how-do-mixpanels-libraries-assign-distinctid-by-default) says:

> If you do not choose to manage distinct_id yourself, each time a user shows up in a new browser, on a new machine, or clears their cookies, they will appear to be a new unique user.

it's similar to session structure so I decided to reuse it, with Laravel I wrote the following for JS library:

```
mixpanel.identify("{{ session()->getId() }}");
mixpanel.track('Some event');
```

And this for PHP library:

```
$mp->identify(session()->getId());
$mp->track('Another event');
```

It's works very well for me.